# Why Eclipse dont generate complete persistence.xml?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jpa, persistence

I have Vaadin project with JPA 2.1 + EclipseLink + MySQL.

In eclipse in project settings I set connection to base and drivers correctly. Without problem I "generate Entities from Tables", but persistence.xml haven't info about driver, connection, login, pass to DB.

My auto generate persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="RadiologicalWarehouse">
        <class>pl.intibs.rw.entitites.Message</class>
        <class>pl.intibs.rw.entitites.Part</class>
        <class>pl.intibs.rw.entitites.Role</class>
        <class>pl.intibs.rw.entitites.Sample</class>
        <class>pl.intibs.rw.entitites.SampleHistory</class>
        <class>pl.intibs.rw.entitites.User</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

If I run my application with simple query, I get of course exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4021] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Unable to acquire a connection from driver [null], user [null] and URL [null].  Verify that you have set the expected driver class and URL.  Check your login, persistence.xml or sessions.xml resource.  The jdbc.driver property should be set to a class that is compatible with your database platform
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:239)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

If JPA has defined the connection in the project, why does not generate this persistence automatically?

Screenshot settings JPA: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyHnq.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I understand you have set parameters for the Jpa plugin to eclipse and this is much different to set the parameters to persistence provider. Firstly you have to decide what persitent provide use and specify it in the persistence.xml together with the others paramenters.

This is an example of persistence.xml with eclipseLink:

```
        <persistence>

        <persistence-unit name="myUnit">
          <provider>yourProvider</provider>

          <class>it.myCompany.domain.MyFirstClass</class>
          <class>it.myCompany.domain.MySecondClassClass</class>

          <properties>

             <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="${driverClass}" />
             <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="${connectionURL}" />
             <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="${username}" />
             <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="${password}" />
             <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="info"/>


          </properties>


          <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>


        </persistence-unit>

    </persistence>
```

Comment: Thanks. I need remowe `<property name="eclipselink.composite-unit.member" value="true"/>`  beacouse of: 
`javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28030] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
    Exception Description: PersistenceUnit [RadiologicalWarehouse] specifies eclipselink.composite-unit.member property with value true. That means it cannot be used standalone, but only as a composite member.`

And `<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>` becouse don't work too.

Comment: Sorry, but I copied an file persistence.xml that is member to a composite persistence unit for this reason there was  <property name="eclipselink.composite-unit.member" value="true"/>. Instead the shared-cache-mode disable the second level cache and it work only if you are using eclipseLink like persistence provider. What persistence provider are you using? Anyway good job

Comment: I use EclipseLink 2.5.0

Comment: What king to exception get if you put shaed-cache-mode?

Comment: `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28030] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException     Exception Description: PersistenceUnit [RadiologicalWarehouse] specifies eclipselink.composite-unit.member property with value true. That means it cannot be used standalone, but only as a composite member.`

Comment: This is right for the **eclipselink.composite-unit.member** property, but if you remove it from the persistence and and let then the property **shared-cache-mode**, What's happens?